# Automatic unique ID generation in database on new entry in visual studio

Tags: c#, database

i want to generate an unique ID on new entry in database ..i am using visual studio 2017 and i have .aspx web form connected to database.  when there new entry occurs database should automatically store unique ID and display it on the screen for user.

Comment: try autoincrement column for that purpose

Answer (score 0):

If your Id is uniqueidentifier, you can use `Guid.NewGuid()`

> Else if Id is int , you can mark it as autoIncrement with seed 1.

It can be autoIncrement guid:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (ColumnA uniqueidentifier DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID());
```